# function as a return value, don't understand the output of an example

Tags: go

The following example prints 12. I can't understand this output. Why did it print 12 and not 11?

```
func fA() func() int {
    i := 0
    return func() int {
        i++
        return i
    }
}
func main() {
   fB := fA()
   fmt.Print(fB())
   fmt.Print(fB())
}
```

Comment: Why would it print `11`?

Comment: In the main function, we have a first call of fb() in which we initialize i by 0 and return the result of a function (that increments i). So, the first print shows 1. The next print with a call to fB() will do the same thing namely initializing i by 0... and prints 1. No ?

Comment: The variable `i` that's initialized by `fA` is "captured" by the returned closure, therefore `fB`, to which you assign the closure, modifies the same variable `i`, every time it's called, incrementing it one by one, call by call.

Comment: *"we have a first call of fb() in which we initialize i by 0"* -- No, `i` is initialized by the call to `fA()`.

Comment: *"fB() will do the same thing namely initializing i by 0"* -- No, `i` is already initialized, `fB()` doesn't initialize anything, it only modifies the variable that was already initialized by the call to `fA()`, and then returns it. Basically you assign `func() int { i++; return i }` to `fB`, do you see any "initialize i by 0" in that function? I know I don't.

Comment: converting to a closure, maybe this makes it more clear: https://go.dev/play/p/GEq8Zw5ruuk

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [closure](https://zetcode.com/golang/closure/#:%7E:text=A%20Go%20closure%20is%20an,new%20instances%20of%20the%20function.&text=We%20create%20an%20anonymous%20function%20which%20adds%20three%20values.). Basically, the function returned knows the variable defined outside its scope, so when you call fA(), the returned function has *i = 0*, when you call fB(), it increments the value of *i*, now *i = 1*. when you call it again it will increment *i* again, and now you have *i = 2*. If you create a new function using fA(), this new function will have a new *i*. Something like this:

```
 fB := fA()
 fC := fA()
 fmt.Print(fB())// 1
 fmt.Print(fB())// 2
 fmt.Print(fC())// 1
 fmt.Print(fB())// 3
```